# Why check-button doesn't show correctly on mobile?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I got this little login page on desktop:

[desk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmTOB.png)

on mobile:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4MEZ.jpg)

html:

```
<section class="flex-container">

  <div class="imagex">
    <img src="./src/rat2.svg" class='rat' alt="" srcset="">
  </div>

  <div class="form-container">
      <input class="form-control form-i" type="text" placeholder="ID">
      <input class="form-control form-i" type="password" placeholder="PASSWORD">
  
      <div class="form-f">
          <input class="form-i check" type="checkbox"">
          <p>REMEMBER ME</p>
      </div>

      <button class="btn btn-primary form-i btnF" type="submit">SIGN</button>
  </div>
</session>
```

why works different ?

Comment: proyect: https://gerrystuff.github.io/SCORES

Answer (score 0):

This bit:

```
  <div class="form-f">
  <input class="form-i check" type="checkbox"">
  <p>REMEMBER ME</p>
</div>
```

You might try like this instead:

```
  <div class="form-control form-f">
  <label><input class="form-control form-i check" type="checkbox"> REMEMBER ME</label>
</div>
```

At the very least I believe you are missing `form-control` as part of your class declaration on at least the check `input`.